# Prove that $L^1$ is a Banach algebra with multiplication defined by convolution

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-algebras

To be more specific, prove that $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with multiplication defined by convolution:
$$
(f\cdot g)(x)=\int_\mathbb{R^n}f(x-y)g(y)dy
$$
is a Banach algebra. All the properties of Banach algebra are easily proved except the last one:
$$
\|f\cdot g\|\le \|f\|\|g\|.
$$
Could anyone give me a hint?

Actually I found a proof on the web, but I don't see why the last equality holds.
$$\|f* g\|_1  = \int |f*g(x)|dx \le \iint |f(x-y) g(y)|dydx = \|f\|_1 \|g\|_1$$

Comment: What about Fubini?

Comment: I edited my question. Now I found a proof on the web, but I don't see why the last equality holds.

Comment: This is a special case of Young's inequality for convolutions by the way, with $p = q = r = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\iint |f(x-y)g(y)|\;dx\;dy &=
\int\left[\int|f(x-y)|\;dx\right]|g(y)|\;dy \\
&= \int\left[\int|f(x)|\;dx\right]|g(y)|\;dy \\
&= \left[\int|f(x)|\;dx\right]\;\left[\int |g(y)| \;dy\right]\\
& = \|f\|_1\;\|g\|_1
\end{align}

Comment: I can see that by variable substitution $\int |f(x-y)|dx$ reduces to $\int |f(x)|dx$. But why isn't $\int |f(x-y)|dx$ a function of $y$? I am confused.

Comment: It is. But you can just shift it since you integrate over all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: But I remember in the calculation of conditional density, by integrating over one variable $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)dy=f_X(x)$ is a function of $x$. What is the difference here?

Comment: Yes, $\int |f(x-y)|dx$ is a function of $y$.  But a calculation shows it is a constant function.

Comment: I managed to get the conclusion that $\int |f(x-y)|dx$ is a constant by using the substitution $t=x-y$. Is there a more enlightening way of doing this? Moreover, I can also conclude that $\int |f(x-y)|dx=\int |f(x-y)|dy$, right?

Comment: "More enlightening" way: the Lebesgue integral is translation invariant.